# Если блок не помещается на текущей странице, то перенести его на следующую

Tags: html, css

Если блок не поместился на текущей странице в печатной форме, нужно сделать его перенос на следующую страницу. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь свойством [`page-break-inside`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/page-break-inside), установив у родительского элемента значение `avoid`:

```css
body {
  page-break-inside: avoid
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>Длинный элемент 1 <img src="" style="height: 220pt" /></div>
    <div>Длинный элемент 2 <img src="" style="height: 220pt" /></div>
</body>
```

Comment: если не ошибаюсь то применяется это свойство при печати и это свойство запрещает разрыв страницы внутри элемента - вот так вроде